# difference in results while using pixel value or int

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

While using Matlab for image processing (exactly improving img by Fuzzy Logic) I found a really strange thing. My fuzzy function is correct, I tested it on random values and they are basically simple linear functions.

```
function f = Udark(z)
if z < 50
    f = 1;
elseif z > 125
    f = 0;
elseif (z >= 50) && (z <= 125)
    f = -z/75 + 125/75;
end

end
```

where z is a value of a pixel (in grayscale). Now there is a really strange thing going on.
`f = -z/75 + 125/75;`, where a is an image. However, it is giving really different results if used as an input. I.e. if I use a variable `p = 99`, the output of the function is `0.3467` as it should be, when if I use A(i,j) it is giving me result `f=2`. Since it is clearly impossible, I do not know where is the problem. I thought that maybe there is a case with the type of the variable but if I change it to uint8 it stays the same... If you know what's going on, please, let me know :)

Comment: How are you calling the function when iterating through the image? Seems like there's probably something wrong with how you're handling the image matrix, not with the code in this function itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1.Changed line:

```
f = (125/75) - (z/75);
```

After editing the third condition the resultant/transformed image has no pixel values of 2. Not sure if you intend to work with decimals. If decimals are necessary using the `im2double()` function to convert the image and scaling it up by a factor of 255 might suffice your needs. See heading 3 for rounding details.

### 2.Reading in Image and Testing:

```
%Reading in the image and applying the function%
Image = imread("RGB_Image.png");
Greyscale_Image = rgb2gray(Image);

[Image_Height,Image_Width] = size(Greyscale_Image);
Transformed_Image = zeros(Image_Height,Image_Width);

for Row = 1: +1: Image_Height
   for Column = 1: +1: Image_Width 
    
    Pixel_Value = Greyscale_Image(Row,Column);
    [Transformed_Pixel_Value] = Udark(Pixel_Value);
    Transformed_Image(Row,Column) = Transformed_Pixel_Value;
   
   end 
end

subplot(1,2,1); imshow(Greyscale_Image);
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(Transformed_Image);

%Checking that no transformed pixels falls in this impossible range%
Check = (Transformed_Image > (125/75)) & (Transformed_Image ~= 1);
Check_Flag = any(Check,'all');


%Function to transform pixel values%
function f = Udark(z)
if z < 50
    f = 1;
elseif z > 125
    f = 0;
elseif (z >= 50) && (z <= 125)
    f = (125/75) - (z/75);
end

end
```

### 3.Evaluating the Specifics of the Third Condition

Working with integers (uint8) will force the values to be rounded to the nearest integer. Any number that falls between the range (50,125] will evaluate to 1 or 0.

```
f = -z/75 + 125/75;
```

If z = 50.1,

-50.1/75 + 125/75 = 74.9/75 ≈ 0.9987 → rounds to 1

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**

Comment: thanks im2double(img) or just double(pixel_value) worked out :)